# How to secure confidential Directories from bots?

Tags: robots.txt

What is the best way to secure some confidential files and directories from bots and crawlers(such as Google bot,..etc).

**Sample Directory Structure :**

```
/folder/
/public_html/
             /includes/ - // Private
             /db/config.php - //Private
             index.php - // Public
             robots.txt - // Public
```

I know i can add these files and directores to robots.txt and disallow them,
but only some bots accept the rules. Also users can read the robots.txt file and view the location of confidential files.

Another option is to put these folders and files outside public_html directory.

So whats in your opinion is the best way to secure them.

Comment: This is an opinion based question as you present it. Just how secure do you want them to be? Seems like you answered yourself, `put these folders and files outside public_html directory.` If you can make it more specific, I can remove my vote to close it.

Comment: Yes thats opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

Of Course, you can't use the robots.txt file to hide your directory and the robots.txt file doesn't even prevent indexing on google.

What you need to do is set up a .htaccess file if you are using Apache server and build rules to hide/redirect and return 404 Error page or maybe 403 access denied.

See this for example http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess.php

The other option is to create a .htaccess file in each private folder and add the following line in that file.

```
deny from all
```

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

Declare what user agents shall not be able to see you excludes

```
User-agent: *
```

This excludes all bots. Or at least it should.

Then exclude your paths

```
Disallow: /something/
Disallow: /something_else/
```

Hope this helps.